# Highcharts .getJSON - chart not plotting

Tags: highcharts, getjson

Previous help here has got me to the current stage with my Highcharts project, however I am still hitting a major stumbling block. Highcharts chart is not loading data retrieved using .getJSON.  I am at a loss as to why the html is not rendering the chart and load the data from data.php. All code below, does anyone have any ideas? @PawełFus

**php**

```
<?php

 $con = mysql_connect("ip_address","root","");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$result = array();

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT unix_timestamp(DATETIMES), TEST FROM PR");

$result['name'] = 'TEST';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $datetime = $r[0]*1000;
     $result['category'][] = $datetime;
     $result['data'][] = round($r[1],2) ;
}

$json = array();
array_push($json,$result);
print json_encode($json);


?>
```

**php return**

```
[{"name":"CCGT","category":[1387791900000,1387792200000,1387792500000,1387792800000],"data":[8389,8478,8761,8980,9050]}]
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'test',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'test'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: []
            }

            $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json['category'];
                options.series[0].name = json['name'];
                options.series[0].data = json['data'];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your series array (in options) has no object, so you cannot use series[0].name. Secondly your json is not used correct, but try to replace this lines:

```
options.xAxis.categories = json['category'];
options.series[0].name = json['name'];
options.series[0].data = json['data'];
```

with

```
options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['category'];
options.series[0] = {};
options.series[0].name = json[0]['name'];
options.series[0].data = json[0]['data'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Seb. Replacing the options line results in partial success. The chart is now rendering (with correct series name), however the data still does not display. Live example here [link](http://energydata.dyndns.org/fiddle10.html) , data.php output is stored here [link](http://energydata.dyndns.org/data.php). Chrome console shows a highcharts.js error 19. Not familiar with Highcharts debugging, any insights?

Comment: Do you use this json or other?

Comment: The json in the original post was for testing purposes and is a subset of the linked json.

Comment: Ahhh... http://www.highcharts.com/errors/19 might explain it, will try to reduce the number of data points in query

Comment: However is there a way around the datetime/category limitation or an alternative way of loading a large series of json datetime data?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, sorry I did not understand your last comment, is there supposed to be a link?